# Accessing the image hash from within the container

Tags: php, docker

Is is possible to access the hash-ID of the image used to create the container, from within the container? I want to provide a 'signature version' at the bottom of each page served from a php app running in a container.

I guess one way is to use Environment Variables from within the docker compose file:

```
environment:
      - IMAGE_HASH=${IMAGE_HASH}
```

and then have a wrapper script first of all write the IMAGE_HASH=ABC123 to a .env file before running docker-compose up. The script can inspect the image to get the hash ID.

But I wonder if there is a 'proper' way to do this? So from within the compose file something like:

```
environment:
    - IMAGE_HASH=this.imagehash
```

Comment: If you add the hash in the image, it will change the image hash. I guess `docker run` could force it in, maybe in a reserved environment variable, but I'm still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, there's no proper way to do this. There are requests to include some kind of [metadata to containers](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/issues/1105), but it would take a change to the runtime spec and then runtimes would need to update to the new spec.

There's also no easy way to include this at build time, because there's a loop in the hashing logic if you try to set an environment variable in the image with the digest of the image. Setting that variable modifies the image config, which changes the digest of the image config, which changes the digest of the manifest which is your image digest.

So at best you're left to do this at runtime with a file or environment variables that you set as part of your container creation process. And I'm not aware of any predefined variables that would help with this.

Perhaps the best method would be to get a [service template](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates) for the image digest, but that may be complicated to implement since compose may point to an image that has yet to be pulled, and so you would end up with registry logic added to compose that docker may want to keep separate. It's also possible to deploy images that haven't been pushed to a registry, which means you would have to do the digest logic in docker, and since that digest is on a byte array from a json export of the manifest, it starts to get complicated (changing field ordering or white space changes the digest without changing the imported json, so you get into canonical json issues).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just read a unique value for the container, there is an environment variable that is already present in every container: `HOSTNAME`, perhaps this what you are looking for?

For example, I use this in some HTML templates on a PHP site, to make sure I download the most recent copy of CSS or JS, in a blade template:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/global.css?_={{ $_ENV['HOSTNAME'] }}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers pointed out why it is difficult.

There is already one workaround in the question. Another possible workaround:

Add an environment variable into your image at build time, based on a random hash (or timestamp or some combination). The hash could be created at the beginning of the build and it should be guaranteed to be used only once.

This self created hash id can then be accessed from inside the running container.

The drawback is, you need to somehow create and use a reference table between the self-created hashes and the docker hash-ids.

You could even tag the images with the self created hash-id. As there are multiple tags possible, it should not create any problems. Depending on the used workflow the tagging could help.

Answer (score 0):

[Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) offers a `--digest-file` flag that writes the image hash into a file inside the container at the end of the build.